# Is there a way to synchronize ajax calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

It may be a trivial question, but I am wondering if there is way to somehow know when the last ajax call gets completed. So lets say I have 3 asynchronous ajax calls

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    datatype: "json",
    url: <my service url 1>
})
.done(function() {
    // handler
});

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    datatype: "json",
    url: <my service url 2>
})
.done(function() {
    // handler
});

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    datatype: "json",
    url: <my service url 3>
})
.done(function() {
    // handler
});
```

I want to show a progress bar when the first call starts and hide it when the last one finish. The issue is that even though I call them in sequence, because calls are asynchronous, I don't know how to tell when all calls finish. I could nest them one inside another, but then as far as I understand it will take much longer as one will have to wait for another to finish. Is there a way to sync it somehow?

Comment: The simplest way would be to have a counter variable and just check `if (counter != 3) return;` in your callback handler.

Comment: I was thinking of that as well, then I have to make sure it also gets handled if call fails

Comment: Just add an error handler that increments it as well :)

Comment: $.when is awesome, thanks to Zzirconium

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used to have the same need. If you can use jQuery, have a look there : http://lostechies.com/joshuaflanagan/2011/10/20/coordinating-multiple-ajax-requests-with-jquery-when/

Otherwise, you can pass a simple callback function through your AJAX call that comes back in your progress indicator update at the end of each async treatment.

Comment: This looks very neat. I will try it out and see if it works. Much better then having to write some counter handling or sync code.

Comment: you'll have to use .then() as shown in the second example of the doc http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/

Comment: Yes, I used $.when(func1(), func2()).then(function(res1, res2) {}).fail(function(){})

Answer (score 2):

Already answered, but consider using global events instead -

[AjaxStart](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/) - Triggered when any ajax call starts
[AjaxStop](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/) - Triggered when all ajax calls are finished

Example -

```
$( document ).ajaxStart(function() {
  $( "#progressBar" ).show();
});

$( document ).ajaxStop(function() {
  $( "#progressBar" ).hide();
});
```

But you will need to make sure that the second call begins before the first call is complete or atleast it should be triggered immediately after the first one completes.